# Error using Crypto Library for Arduino: Speck

Tags: arduino-uno, library

I'm trying to encrypt a string in my Arduino Uno using the following library:

https://github.com/rweather/arduinolibs/tree/master/libraries/Crypto

And I'm getting this error:

> In function 'void setup()':
>
> TESTING_SPECK_LIB:27: error: request for member 'setKey' in
>   '*(byte*)(& cipher)', which is of non-class type 'byte {aka unsigned
>   char}'
>
> cipher->setKey(*key,keySize);
>
> exit status 1 request for member 'setKey' in '*(byte*)(& cipher)',
>   which is of non-class type 'byte {aka unsigned char}'

This is the code I'm using:

```
#include <Crypto.h>
#include <Speck.h>
#include <SpeckSmall.h>
#include <SpeckTiny.h>
#include <string.h>


Speck speck;
SpeckSmall speckSmall;
SpeckTiny speckTiny;

byte buffer[16];
byte cipher[16];
size_t keySize = 32;

void setup() {

  const uint8_t key[32]={0x0f, 0x0e, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x09, 0x08,
                    0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00};
  byte plaintext[16]={0x6c, 0x61, 0x76, 0x69, 0x75, 0x71, 0x65, 0x20,
                    0x74, 0x69, 0x20, 0x65, 0x64, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x20};
  byte ciphertext[16]={0xa6, 0x5d, 0x98, 0x51, 0x79, 0x78, 0x32, 0x65,
                    0x78, 0x60, 0xfe, 0xdf, 0x5c, 0x57, 0x0d, 0x18};

  Serial.begin(9600);

  cipher->setKey(*key,keySize);
  cipher->encryptBlock(buffer, plaintext);

}

void loop() {

}
```

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't understand what the error means, someone knows what it means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`byte cipher[16];` declares `cipher` as an array of 16 bytes.  As such, `cipher` has no methods, much less ones called `setKey()` or `encryptBlock()`.

Note, `setKey()` and `encryptBlock()` look like method names one would find in `Crypto` or `Speck` library code; however, I don't find them in the `Crypto` and `Speck` headers I looked at on github sites.  Also, `buffer`, `cipher`, and `keySize` look like variables and parameters one would use in creating an object for use with encryption methods.

In short, it appears your code fails to set up an appropriate class of objects that have `setKey()` and `encryptBlock()` methods.

Note, while I am not familiar with their details, I question whether all of the header files `Speck.h`, `SpeckSmall.h`, and `SpeckTiny.h` should be included in your code.  It seems more likely that you would choose one of them as appropriate to your needs.

---

*Edit 1:*  Looking at [`TestSpeck.ino`](https://github.com/rweather/arduinolibs/blob/master/libraries/Crypto/examples/TestSpeck/TestSpeck.ino) as mentioned in `per1234 6`'s comment, one sees a function `perfCipher()`, with its first argument declared as `BlockCipher *cipher`.  That is, `cipher` is declared as an object of a class that has `setKey()` and `encryptBlock()` methods.

The `TestSpeck.ino` sketch includes all three of the header files `Speck.h`, `SpeckSmall.h`, and `SpeckTiny.h` because it runs performance tests that compare results using different `Speck` implementations.  In practice you usually won't need more than one of those headers.

Comment: See https://github.com/rweather/arduinolibs/blob/master/libraries/Crypto/examples/TestSpeck/TestSpeck.ino indeed it does include all three of those files. I'm guessing each adds an additional layer of functionality. That example declares an array named `ciphertext`, not `cypher`. I suspect OP confused the two, thus the error.

Comment: @per1234, thanks, have edited a note about that